# Building a Dynamic MySQL Query Based on Multiple Variables and Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, conditional-statements

I am hoping this title represents this question well.  I am attempting to build a dynamic query based on multiple $vars existing.  I am attempting to make this work using a simple if/ifelse/else block but can't seem to get it to work correctly.  The first if statements execute accordingly but the third fails.  I am new to PHP so I am assuming this a beginner mistake.  I also believe there is most likely a far more eloquent way to achieve the desired results.

Basically the user enters a few inputs into multiple text fields.  Only one field, out of the 3 needs to contain a value, but 2 or all 3 can as well.  If the value does not exist in a field it should generate a Query based on the values provided.  I am validating and a creating a variable for each input than checking to see if those variables contain a value or exist.

```
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if(isset($_POST['inputName']) && $_POST['inputName'] != ""){
  $inputName = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['inputName']);
  }

  if(isset($_POST['inputState']) && $_POST['inputState'] != ""){
  $inputState = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['inputState']);
  }

  if(isset($_POST['inputCost']) && $_POST['inputCost'] != ""){
  $inputCost = preg_replace('#[0-9]#i', '', $_POST['inputCost']);
  }

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (!empty($inputName) AND !empty($inputState) AND !empty($inputCost)){
  $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM hciproject WHERE school_name LIKE '%$inputName%' AND school_state LIKE '%$inputState%' AND school_cost < '$inputCost'";
  }
  elseif (!empty($inputName) AND !empty($inputState)){
  $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM hciproject WHERE school_name LIKE '%$inputName%' AND    school_state LIKE '%$inputState%'";
  }
  elseif (!empty($inputName) AND !empty($inputCost)){
  $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM hciproject WHERE school_name LIKE '%$inputName%' AND school_cost < '$inputCost'";
  }
  elseif (!empty($inputState) AND !empty($inputCost)){
  $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM hciproject WHERE school_state LIKE '%$inputState%' AND school_cost < '$inputCost'";
  }
  else{
  $searchOut .= "0 Results Found";
  }


  // Connect to DB
  include_once("database_connection.php"); 

  $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
  $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Additionally I was going to create elseif statements containing only one variable.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly ?

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin when I was entering values into the fields and testing each if/elseif statement only the first two were executing properly and building the appropriate query.  Basically only the 'if' and the first 'elseif' statement were executing, but not the following one.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 $inputName = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '',& $_POST['inputName']);
 $inputState = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '',& $_POST['inputState']);
 $inputCost = preg_replace('#[0-9]#i', '',& $_POST['inputCost']);

 $selectCondition = 1; 
 if($inputName) $selectCondition.= " and school_name LIKE '%$inputName%' ";
 if($inputState ) $selectCondition.= " and school_state  LIKE '%$inputState%' ";
 if($inputCost ) $selectCondition.= " and school_cost < $inputCos ";
```

Important:

```
 & $_POST['inputName'] is equal to (isset($_POST['inputName']) && $_POST['inputName'] != "")
```

Comment: I couldn't seem to get this to work.  Maybe I am simply implementing it incorrectly.  I do not know which fields the user will fill out, therefore I cannot use the "AND" attribute for each $selectCondition.  Say the user was only to enter a name for the school only the $inputName var would contain a variable, but the other two variables would be empty.